# redirect 81 to 443 in nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

I'm trying to get all traffic served as https. However the server is behind a AWS ELB. So I've setup a listener on the ELB to direct 80 -> 81 and 443 -> 80
i.e. all http traffic goes to port 81 on the rails server.
And all https traffic goes to port 80 (ssl terminated on the ELB)
I'm trying to get nginx to redirect all port 81 traffic to https.
Seems simple enough.

So I have a server block called redirect_to_ssl in the sites_available directory
it looks like this:

```
server {
      listen         81;
      server_name    redirect_to_ssl;
      return         301 https://$hostname$request_uri;
}
```

I've symlinked this file into sites-enabled

And I've reloaded the config for nginx

But when I try and curl localhost:81 I get connection refused. And when I try and browse the site from outside the ELB, it does nothing

Any ideas? Is there another way of doing what I'm trying to do with AWS ELB's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directive `server_name` is not a label, it's the name of the virtual server, i.e. its value must match with HTTP Host header of ingoing requests for the server block to be accessed. So it will likely never match any Host actual host header in use with your setup and never be reached.

Read the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name).

The use of `$hostname` is also weird if you use a load balancer ...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it without the server_name to start with. It never worked. SO I looked at the current website and the server_name for that is simply the folder name of the ruby app. No relation to the domain its being served on?

Comment: The weird thing is that I get Connection refused when I'm on the server doing a curl to 127.0.0.1:81

Comment: @Bernard The folder name ? Your setup is completely broken, get [some nginx basic knowledge](http://nginx.org/en/docs/) then you will have a clearer view. If you have connection refused then nginx is not listening on that port because either it didn't start or the configuration is bad or a firewall is sending TCP resets for that port.

Comment: The ruby app is called my_app for example. And its deployed into a folder called my_app elsewhere.
There is a server block file called my_app in the sites-available folder. And in that server block file, the server_name is my_app. 
Not sure how else to explain this?
I didn't set this up - that's a default config for Opsworks. And my setup is not completely broken :) It works perfectly. The only thing that doesn't work is the redirect to port 81.
I have since found out that this was due to the AWS security group for that server not allowing port 81.
Thanks for the help